# Android:CheckedTextView isChecked returns incorrect value

Tags: android, checkedtextview

> Android version: 3.1 
> API version: Android 2.2 
> Device: Motorola MX604

I dynamically create a multi-select ListView of CheckedTextView items, and attach a OnItemClickListener to the ListView.  In the onItemClick method of the listener, I invoke the isChecked method of CheckedTextView to determine if the associated checkbox is checked or unchecked.  Simple enough.

The problem: When I select a previously unselected item, the isChecked method returns false. When I select a previously selected item, the method returns true.  The checkbox icon itself checks and unchecks correctly.

Here is the layout for the CheckedTextView:

```
    <CheckedTextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical" 
    android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple" 
    android:paddingLeft="6dip" android:paddingRight="6dip" 
    />
```

This is how I create the ListView:

```
    private void createSortedChannelList() {

    emptyViewContainer();

    ListView sortedListView = new ListView(this);
    sortedListView.setId(CHANNEL_LISTVIEW_ID);
    sortedListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    sortedListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);

    sortedListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {

            CheckedTextView selectedItem = (CheckedTextView) view;
            boolean isChecked = selectedItem.isChecked();
            Log.e(mLogTag,"item clicked position = " + position + " isChecked = " + isChecked);

        }

    });

    ArrayAdapter<Channel> listAdapter = 
        new ArrayAdapter<Channel>(this,R.layout.favorite_channel_list_select_channel_row,mAllChannels);
    sortedListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    for(int channelIndex = 0;channelIndex < mChannelIds.length;channelIndex++){
        if(mSelectedChannelIds.contains(mChannelIds[channelIndex]))
            sortedListView.setItemChecked(channelIndex, true);
    }

    addViewToViewContainer(sortedListView);

}
```

This is the log output that is produced when I select a previously unselected item:

```
09-23 09:08:59.650: item clicked position = 19 isChecked = false
```

and when I select a previously selected item

```
09-23 09:10:20.800: item clicked position = 18 isChecked = true
```

I have done an extensive search and I can only find one other report of similar behavior.  This leads me to believe that the problem probably lies in my code, rather than the android class :p  I have also looked at numerous examples that are set up in a similar fashion. Can anyone spot a problem?

thanks

PS This is my first post on any forum, so if I'm missing something that would be helpful to the readers of this post, please let me know.

Comment: Does clicking the item again show the opposite return to `isChecked()`?

Comment: Yes.  The first time a previously unselected is selected, it returns false.  If the same item is selected again it returns true.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the code is behaving the way it should.  Selecting a previously unselected method will invoke the click listener before changing the checked state of the item in the list.  In other words, `isChecked()` won't return true for the previously unselected item until after the `onClick()` method is finished.

Comment: That does seem to be the way it is working.  Unfortunately, the isChecked method is the only method in the CheckedTextView class with no javadoc.  thanks

Comment: I have seen a similar issue, but I'm not sure it's consistent.  When I ran some code in an emulator, it worked the way described here (IE, isChecked() returns the "pre-click" state of the item), but when I ran the same code on an actual device, it worked just the opposite (isChecked() returned the "post-click" state).

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that for me, at least, the behavior of when the state changes isn't consistent; on an emulator, isChecked() returned the pre-click state, but on a device it returned the post-click state.

I got around this by bypassing the "isChecked" altogether, and just looking at the state of the underlying object I am toggling, since that won't change unless I explicitly do so.  However, this solution may depend on how your code is set up, and there may be other gotcha's that I am overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `MultiChoiceModeListener` for listening to checks. [Here is the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener.html)

Comment: I looked at using the MultiChoiceModeListener initially.  It requires API level 11 and the application is at API level 8.